# Computed Column is not allowed to be used in another computed-column definition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I get Computed Column is not allowed to be used in another computed-column
 definition error message when i tried to use a computed field in another computed field. is there any workaround to accomplish this?

Computed field1

```
ALTER TABLE DBO.[ASSy] ADD [CALC STOCK NO] AS (

CASE 
WHEN isnull([DIRECTIONAL TREAD],'') ='YES RIGHT' THEN isnull([STOCK NO],'')+'R'
WHEN isnull([DIRECTIONAL TREAD],'') ='YES LEFT' THEN isnull([STOCK NO],'')+'L'
ELSE isnull([STOCK NO],'')
end 
)
```

Below is the second computed field. when i execute the script i get

> Msg 1759, Level 16, State 0, Line 5 Computed column 'CALC STOCK NO' in
>   table 'ASSy' is not allowed to be used in another
>   computed-column definition.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[ASSy] ADD [PN & DESCRIPTION] AS (ISNULL([CALC STOCK NO],'')+ ', '+ISNULL([TIRE SIZE],'')+', '+ ISNULL([BH SPEC],''))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per [Computed Columns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx) documentation:

> A computed column is computed from an expression that can use other
>   columns in the same table. **The expression can be a noncomputed column
>   name, constant, function, and any combination of these connected by
>   one or more operators.** The expression cannot be a subquery.

A computed column cannot reference another computed column. You have these options:

1. Create a second computed column that includes the same logic as the first computed column (which cannot be referenced).
2. Replace the first computed column with an ordinary column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE DBO.[ASSy] DROP COLUMN [CALC STOCK NO]
ALTER TABLE ADD [CALC STOCK NO] VARCHAR(100) NULL
UPDATE TABLE t
    SET [CALC STOCK NO] = 
        CASE 
        WHEN isnull([DIRECTIONAL TREAD],'') ='YES RIGHT' THEN isnull([STOCK NO],'')+'R'
        WHEN isnull([DIRECTIONAL TREAD],'') ='YES LEFT' THEN isnull([STOCK NO],'')+'L'
        ELSE isnull([STOCK NO],'')
        END
FROM [CALC STOCK NO] t
```

3. Create a `VIEW` on top of the table and implement your second column in it:

```sql
CREATE VIEW DBO.[vASSy]
AS
SELECT   t.*
        ,[PN & DESCRIPTION] = (ISNULL([CALC STOCK NO],'')+ ', '+ISNULL([TIRE SIZE],'')+', '+ ISNULL([BH SPEC],''))
FROM DBO.[ASSy] t
```

Comment: Serge one question i am going to use the View created in c# application so is inserting to this view will also insert the same to the table 'ASSy' or vise versa right?. INSERT statement to the view  `vASSy` will also affect `ASSy`

Comment: Yes, the view is simply that - it is NOT a real table. In many cases you *can* execute INSERT statements on a view, but there are some restrictions. Take a look at [Updatable Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx#Updatable%20Views) section of `CREATE VIEW` documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Not allowed.

Workarounds are to repeat the entire code in the other column's definition or encapsulate the shared code in a scalar UDF or pull the logic up to a view (which is typically sufficient if it's not a persisted column for indexing purposes)

Comment: This is also a valid option. However, be aware that scalar UDF's force the query optimizer to generate serial (not parallel) plans, which may diminish query performance significantly. If logic encapsulation is what you really want to do, create an [inline table-valued function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294(v=sql.105).aspx) instead.